# What is the correct way of adding rounded corners to full screen BottomSheetDialogFragment with Jetpack Compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, bottomsheetdialogfragment

I have a BottomSheetDialogFragment like this:

```
class MyFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {


    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val dialog = BottomSheetDialog(requireContext(), theme)
        dialog.setOnShowListener {
            val bottomSheetDialog = it as BottomSheetDialog
            val parentLayout =
                bottomSheetDialog.findViewById<View>(com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet)
            parentLayout?.let { view ->
                val behaviour = BottomSheetBehavior.from(view)
                setupFullHeight(view)
                behaviour.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
                behaviour.skipCollapsed = true
            }
        }
        return dialog
    }

    private fun setupFullHeight(bottomSheet: View) {
        val layoutParams = bottomSheet.layoutParams
        layoutParams.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        bottomSheet.layoutParams = layoutParams
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
            setContent {
                AppTheme {
                    setViewCompositionStrategy(ViewCompositionStrategy.DisposeOnViewTreeLifecycleDestroyed)
                    Scaffold(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize()
                            .nestedScroll(rememberNestedScrollInteropConnection())
                    ) {
                        LazyColumn(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxSize()
                                .padding(it)
                        ) {
                            // here some items
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What should I do so that the edges of the full screen dialog can be rounded? I've seen solutions for Android and XML, but they didn't work for me.

When I give `.clip(RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 10.dp, topEnd = 10.dp))` to Scaffold, a background non-transparency problem occurs.

[image]

Comment: Maybe consider using Material 3 : https://m3.material.io/components/bottom-sheets/overview . Then it's rounded out-of-the-box...

Comment: As seen in the overview, Material 3 BottomSheet for Jetpack Compose is not available.

Comment: Ugh, sorry my bad...

Comment: You need to animate corner radius on going from half expanded to fully expanded. That will smoothly transition to round corders to edge.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
    ModalBottomSheetLayout(
        sheetState = modalBottomSheetState,
        sheetShape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 10.dp, topEnd = 10.dp),
....)
```